# SQS Source connector not producing message in JSON format

Tags: apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka SQS Source connector which consume message from AWS SQS Queue and publish messages to Kafka topic. All my messages are in JSON format but SQS source connector publish message in a different format. For example below:

```
Struct{ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=3839487494849,ApproximateReceiveCount=1,SenderId=LDOEKDSDKEKSDSDS,SentTimestamp=47394749393,Body=[
   {
        "id": "28292",
        "name": "apple"
    }
]}
```

How to get rid of this `Struct{ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp=3839487494849,ApproximateReceiveCount=1,SenderId=LDOEKDSDKEKSDSDS,SentTimestamp=47394749393,Body=[`

and get only JSON message like below:

```
 {
        "id": "28292",
        "name": "apple"
    }
```

I see [Value Schema](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/sqs/current/overview.html#value-schema) return **struct** instead of **JSON**, how can I get message in String or JSON format?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get `Struct{}` if you are using `StringConverter`. If you have JSON, then use `JsonConverter`.

**However**, this may return

```
{
  "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp" : 3839487494849, 
  other metadata fields from the docs...
  "body": "{\"id\":\"28292\" ...
}
```

And you'll need to use some stream processing to parse the body string.